# How to Check if Cookie is Disabled from Next.js App

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, cookies

I have a Next.js App. It works fine until I disable the cookie from Browser. Is there a way I can check if Cookie are disabled in browser and then show a message accordingly. I tried checking using `navigator` inside _app.js

```
    useEffect(()=>{
        if(navigator && !navigator.cookieEnabled){
            setCookieEnabled(false);
        }
        setLoading(false);
    },[]);
```

But it breaks even before that and I get the following error in safari browser,

> SecurityError: The operation is insecure.

From Chrome browser the error is ,

```
I have a Next.js App. It works fine until I disable the cookie from Browser. Is there a way I can check if Cookie are disabled in browser and then show a message accordingly. I tried checking using `navigator` inside _app.js
```

```
    useEffect(()=>{
        if(navigator && !navigator.cookieEnabled){
            setCookieEnabled(false);
        }
        setLoading(false);
    },[]);
```

But it breaks even before that and I get the following error in safari browser,

> SecurityError: The operation is insecure.

From Chrome browser the error is ,

> Uncaught DOMException: Failed to read the 'localStorage' property from 'Window': Access is denied for this document.
> at eval (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/paho-mqtt/paho-mqtt.js:100:28)
> at LibraryFactory (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/paho-mqtt/paho-mqtt.js:2384:4)
> at ExportLibrary (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/paho-mqtt/paho-mqtt.js:86:20)
> at eval (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/paho-mqtt/paho-mqtt.js:88:3)
> at ./node_modules/paho-mqtt/paho-mqtt.js (https://ecom.sit.mywebsite.co:3000/_next/static/chunks/pages/login/%5B%5B...slug%5D%5D.js?ts=1703679353466:27930:1)
> at options.factory (https://ecom.sit.mywebsite.co:3000/_next/static/chunks/webpack.js?ts=1703679353466:728:31)
> at **webpack_require** (https://ecom.sit.mywebsite.co:3000/_next/static/chunks/webpack.js?ts=1703679353466:37:33)
> at fn (https://ecom.sit.mywebsite.co:3000/_next/static/chunks/webpack.js?ts=1703679353466:383:21)
> at eval (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@aws-amplify/pubsub/lib-esm/Providers/MqttOverWSProvider.js:7:67)
> at ./node_modules/@aws-amplify/pubsub/lib-esm/Providers/MqttOverWSProvider.js (https://ecom.sit.mywebsite.co:3000/_next/static/chunks/pages/login/%5B%5B...slug%5D%5D.js?ts=1703679353466:5217:1)
> at options.factory (https://ecom.sit.mywebsite.co:3000/_next/static/chunks/webpack.js?ts=1703679353466:728:31)
> at **webpack_require** (https://ecom.sit.mywebsite.co:3000/_next/static/chunks/webpack.js?ts=1703679353466:37:33)
> at fn (https://ecom.sit.mywebsite.co:3000/_next/static/chunks/webpack.js?ts=1703679353466:383:21)
> at eval (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@aws-amplify/pubsub/lib-esm/Providers/AWSAppSyncProvider.js:8:77)
> at ./node_modules/@aws-amplify/pubsub/lib-esm/Providers/AWSAppSyncProvider.js (https://ecom.sit.mywebsite.co:3000/_next/static/chunks/pages/login/%5B%5B...slug%5D%5D.js?ts=1703679353466:5184:1)
> at options.factory (https://ecom.sit.mywebsite.co:3000/_next/static/chunks/webpack.js?ts=1703679353466:728:31)
> at **webpack_require** (https://ecom.sit.mywebsite.co:3000/_next/static/chunks/webpack.js?ts=1703679353466:37:33)
> at fn (https://ecom.sit.mywebsite.co:3000/_next/static/chunks/webpack.js?ts=1703679353466:383:21)
> at eval (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@aws-amplify/pubsub/lib-esm/Providers/index.js:11:77)
> at ./node_modules/@aws-amplify/pubsub/lib-esm/Providers/index.js (https://ecom.sit.mywebsite.co:3000/_next/static/chunks/pages/login/%5B%5B...slug%5D%5D.js?ts=1703679353466:5250:1)
> at options.factory (https://ecom.sit.mywebsite.co:3000/_next/static/chunks/webpack.js?ts=1703679353466:728:31)
> at **webpack_require** (https://ecom.sit.mywebsite.co:3000/_next/static/chunks/webpack.js?ts=1703679353466:37:33)
> at fn (https://ecom.sit.mywebsite.co:3000/_next/static/chunks/webpack.js?ts=1703679353466:383:21)
> at eval (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@aws-amplify/pubsub/lib-esm/PubSub.js:9:68)
> at ./node_modules/@aws-amplify/pubsub/lib-esm/PubSub.js (https://ecom.sit.mywebsite.co:3000/_next/static/chunks/pages/login/%5B%5B...slug%5D%5D.js?ts=1703679353466:5261:1)
> at options.factory (https://ecom.sit.mywebsite.co:3000/_next/static/chunks/webpack.js?ts=1703679353466:728:31)
> at **webpack_require** (https://ecom.sit.mywebsite.co:3000/_next/static/chunks/webpack.js?ts=1703679353466:37:33)
> at fn (https://ecom.sit.mywebsite.co:3000/_next/static/chunks/webpack.js?ts=1703679353466:383:21)
> at eval (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@aws-amplify/pubsub/lib-esm/index.js:14:65)
> at ./node_modules/@aws-amplify/pubsub/lib-esm/index.js (https://ecom.sit.mywebsite.co:3000/_next/static/chunks/pages/login/%5B%5B...slug%5D%5D.js?ts=1703679353466:5272:1)
> at options.factory (https://ecom.sit.mywebsite.co:3000/_next/static/chunks/webpack.js?ts=1703679353466:728:31)
> at **webpack_require** (https://ecom.sit.mywebsite.co:3000/_next/static/chunks/webpack.js?ts=1703679353466:37:33)
> at fn (https://ecom.sit.mywebsite.co:3000/_next/static/chunks/webpack.js?ts=1703679353466:383:21)
> at eval (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@aws-amplify/api-graphql/lib-esm/GraphQLAPI.js:10:77)
> at ./node_modules/@aws-amplify/api-graphql/lib-esm/GraphQLAPI.js (https://ecom.sit.mywebsite.co:3000/_next/static/chunks/pages/login/%5B%5B...slug%5D%5D.js?ts=1703679353466:354:1)
> at options.factory (https://ecom.sit.mywebsite.co:3000/_next/static/chunks/webpack.js?ts=1703679353466:728:31)
> at **webpack_require** (https://ecom.sit.mywebsite.co:3000/_next/static/chunks/webpack.js?ts=1703679353466:37:33)
> at fn (https://ecom.sit.mywebsite.co:3000/_next/static/chunks/webpack.js?ts=1703679353466:383:21)
> at eval (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@aws-amplify/api-graphql/lib-esm/index.js:9:69)
> at ./node_modules/@aws-amplify/api-graphql/lib-esm/index.js (https://ecom.sit.mywebsite.co:3000/_next/static/chunks/pages/login/%5B%5B...slug%5D%5D.js?ts=1703679353466:365:1)
> at options.factory (https://ecom.sit.mywebsite.co:3000/_next/static/chunks/webpack.js?ts=1703679353466:728:31)
> at **webpack_require** (https://ecom.sit.mywebsite.co:3000/_next/static/chunks/webpack.js?ts=1703679353466:37:33)
> at fn (https://ecom.sit.mywebsite.co:3000/_next/static/chunks/webpack.js?ts=1703679353466:383:21)
> at eval (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@aws-amplify/api/lib-esm/API.js:10:82)
> at ./node_modules/@aws-amplify/api/lib-esm/API.js (https://ecom.sit.mywebsite.co:3000/_next/static/chunks/pages/login/%5B%5B...slug%5D%5D.js?ts=1703679353466:442:1)
> at options.factory (https://ecom.sit.mywebsite.co:3000/_next/static/chunks/webpack.js?ts=1703679353466:728:31)
> at **webpack_require** (https://ecom.sit.mywebsite.co:3000/_next/static/chunks/webpack.js?ts=1703679353466:37:33)
> at fn (https://ecom.sit.mywebsite.co:3000/_next/static/chunks/webpack.js?ts=1703679353466:383:21)
> at eval (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@aws-amplify/api/lib-esm/index.js:9:62)
> at ./node_modules/@aws-amplify/api/lib-esm/index.js (https://ecom.sit.mywebsite.co:3000/_next/static/chunks/pages/login/%5B%5B...slug%5D%5D.js?ts=1703679353466:453:1)
> eval @ index.js:602
> setTimeout (async)
> eval @ index.js:601
> asyncGeneratorStep @ _async_to_generator.js:13
> _next @ _async_to_generator.js:31
> Promise.then (async)
> asyncGeneratorStep @ _async_to_generator.js:22
> _next @ _async_to_generator.js:31
> Promise.then (async)
> asyncGeneratorStep @ _async_to_generator.js:22
> _next @ _async_to_generator.js:31
> eval @ _async_to_generator.js:36
> eval @ _async_to_generator.js:28
> _hydrate @ index.js:641
> hydrate @ index.js:528
> eval @ next-dev.js:40
> Promise.then (async)
> eval @ next-dev.js:35
> ./node_modules/next/dist/client/next-dev.js @ main.js?ts=1703679353466:236
> options.factory @ webpack.js?ts=1703679353466:728
> **webpack_require** @ webpack.js?ts=1703679353466:37
> **webpack_exec** @ main.js?ts=1703679353466:1060
> (anonymous) @ main.js?ts=1703679353466:1061
> webpackJsonpCallback @ webpack.js?ts=1703679353466:1313
> (anonymous) @ main.js?ts=1703679353466:9
> client.bundle.js:1 Uncaught DOMException: Failed to read the 'localStorage' property from 'Window': Access is denied for this document.
> at o (chrome-extension://npbfdllefekhdplbkdigpncggmojpefi/client.bundle.js:1:111601)
> at i (chrome-extension://npbfdllefekhdplbkdigpncggmojpefi/client.bundle.js:1:111786)
> at chrome-extension://npbfdllefekhdplbkdigpncggmojpefi/client.bundle.js:1:36977
> at Y (chrome-extension://npbfdllefekhdplbkdigpncggmojpefi/client.bundle.js:1:37299)
> at chrome-extension://npbfdllefekhdplbkdigpncggmojpefi/client.bundle.js:1:125707
> at _ (chrome-extension://npbfdllefekhdplbkdigpncggmojpefi/client.bundle.js:1:119042)
> at se (chrome-extension://npbfdllefekhdplbkdigpncggmojpefi/client.bundle.js:1:125700)
> at chrome-extension://npbfdllefekhdplbkdigpncggmojpefi/client.bundle.js:1:108600
> at chrome-extension://npbfdllefekhdplbkdigpncggmojpefi/client.bundle.js:1:128706
> at E.s (chrome-extension://npbfdllefekhdplbkdigpncggmojpefi/client.bundle.js:1:118294)
> at z (chrome-extension://npbfdllefekhdplbkdigpncggmojpefi/client.bundle.js:1:122535)
> at E (chrome-extension://npbfdllefekhdplbkdigpncggmojpefi/client.bundle.js:1:118339)
> at i (chrome-extension://npbfdllefekhdplbkdigpncggmojpefi/client.bundle.js:1:128675)
> at Sn (chrome-extension://npbfdllefekhdplbkdigpncggmojpefi/client.bundle.js:1:108586)
> at chrome-extension://npbfdllefekhdplbkdigpncggmojpefi/client.bundle.js:1:171281
> at chrome-extension://npbfdllefekhdplbkdigpncggmojpefi/client.bundle.js:1:171297

Can anyone point me the right direction about how to achieve this. Thanks

Comment: Looking into the error, it seems that it's happening due to the "paho-mqtt" package. Is it this package? [paho-mqtt](https://www.npmjs.com/package/paho-mqtt?activeTab=readme). If yes then look into this [PR](https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.javascript/pull/247)

Answer (score 1):

I recommend to put this in a Wrapper (or Layout) at very top of the app

```
const VerifyCookies = ({ children }) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    var cookieEnabled = navigator.cookieEnabled;
    if (!cookieEnabled) {
      document.cookie = "testcookie";
      cookieEnabled = document.cookie.indexOf("testcookie") != -1;
    } else {
      showCookieFail();
    }
  }, []);
  const showCookieFail = () => {
    //doSomething
  };
  return children;
};
```